# How to create a text file to run wine application on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, wine

I have installed a windows application using wine and I tried to create a text file on desktop containing the following line:

```
wine ".wine/drive_c/Program Files/app1/app2018/app.exe"
```

then I saved the file as a `.sh` file and I made the file executable to be able to open this application directly by double clicking the text file, but it didn't work.

Note that when I write the same line in terminal the application opens directly with no problems.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did you include the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on the script?

Comment: I didn't include the Shebang on the script. I just wrote the line in the text editor and saved as .sh then made executable

Comment: You need to include the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) on the very first line of the script so it can run correctly.

Comment: I added it now but it also didn't work for me. I tried now also to add 'sudo' before my line to help open and opened in terminal but it also didn't work.

Comment: Yes, this was right. I actually found a duplication. Thank you very much